# Raspberry Pi Smbus I2C communication Arduino throw Erro 121

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I've been trying to send commands from a Raspberry PI 3 to an Arduino using the I2C bus with the Smbus library.
The code is written so you can send PWM value from the raspberry to the arduino to drive motors while the arduino is returning variables about motor speed.
The detection is working and the program runs several epochs until it crashes throwing Error 121 Remote I/O.
After lots of search on the web I tried to apply fixes to overcome the issue but nothing seems to work.

Python Code throwing errors

```
bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x13, 0, data) # Error 121 after a random runtime


block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x13, 0, numBytes) # Error 121 after a random runtime
```

I am exploring next solutions:

1. Force program to rerun on errors (smbus throwing error cause the whole script to stop)
2. Set i2c clock frequency
3. Use time.sleep in program to let the I2C commands completely execute

It seems that the connection become unstable when changes occurs to the motors (speed, direction), there is possibly noise from these charges on the circuit.

Is it possible to ignore error, flush the bus for extra informations and restart de process?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Usually it means lost arbitration. Often this may sign about signal jitter that eventually become significant. Check with oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found a post on raspberry stackexchange pointing to the issue I faced.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104975/how-to-automatically-rerun-python-script-if-error-occurs

```
while True:
  <all your code>

  if <some error occurs>:
     time.sleep(10)
     continue
```

the proper statement is to use try and except IOError calling continue on error

```
while True:
    try:
       bus.write_byte()

    except IOError:
       continue
```

This ignore bus communication error and continue running the program. On next epoch the function will run again.

Looking for a way to clear the bus with left datas.